# Check input until end of line of a text file

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a simple login system where the user inputs their ID and the compiler scans through each line of a text file to check if it matches. Unfortunately, upon printing out what the compiler is reading, it reads the ENTIRE file instead of checking line by line, why?

```
int getID() {
    char loginID[10];
    printf("Enter login credentials\nStaff ID:");
    scanf("%s", loginID);
    FILE* file = fopen("Text.txt", "r");
    char IDcheck[10];
    while (fgets(IDcheck, sizeof(IDcheck), file)) {
        printf("%s", IDcheck);
        if (loginID == IDcheck) {
            printf("Logged in successfully");
            pass1 = 1;//is a global variable set to 0;allows the loop to exit
        }
        if (IDcheck == EOF) {
            printf("Record not found! Enter again!");
            pass1 = 0;//gets user to type again
        }
    }
    return pass1;
}
```

This is the Text.txt file in question:

```
ABCD12345
EFGH67890
```

Comment: You don't use `==` to compare strings in C, you use the `strcmp()` function. Also, `fgets()` leave the newline at the end of the input, you need to remove that before comparing with the user's input. `IDcheck == EOF` makes no sense; `IDcheck` is an array, `EOF` is an integer.

Comment: You don't need the `EOF` check. The `while` condition checks for that.

Comment: You should break out of the loop when you find the matching line.

Comment: You're missing the declaration of `pass1`. Initialize it to `false` at the beginning, set it to `true` when you find a match.

Comment: `char loginID[10];` can hold a string of a maximum of `9` characters plus the nul-terminating character `'\0'` (or just plain `0`).  Same for `char IDcheck[10];`. While that may be fine for your data, there is nothing to prevent the user from typing `"12345678901"` which will invoke *Undefined Behavior* by writing beyond the end of `loginID[10]`. Never skimp on buffer-size... and never use `scanf()` to fill an array without providing the *field-width* modifier to protect your array bounds (or better, take all user-input with `fgets()` and trim the `'\n'`).